# Filter aws cli command for secretsmanager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

AWS cli version used on Mac :
aws-cli/1.20.35 Python/3.9.9 Darwin/20.6.0 botocore/1.21.35

Command :
`aws --profile new secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id testsecret --output text --query SecretString`

Output:
`{"passwd":"xxx"}`

How do I get only 'xxx'?

Answer (score 0):

Got this from doc - If this secret was created by using the console, then Secrets Manager stores the information as a JSON structure of key/value pairs.
Created the secret via aws-cli. Then the output of get-secret-value is 'xxx'.